# verbe modal + pas encore

Tags: syntaxe

I recently wrote this sentence:

> Je ne voulais pas encore pleurer.

To my mind, it's ambiguous whether *pas encore* attaches to *voulais* or to *pleurer*, yielding these paraphrases respectively:

1. Later on I might want to cry, but I didn't yet have such a desire.
2. I wanted to cry, but not for said crying to happen yet.

First, am I correct to detect such an ambiguity? Second, what would be your recommended ways to express each unambiguously without a lengthy paraphrase?

It seems to me that I could get sense (1) like this:

> Je n'avais pas encore envie de pleurer.

But this is as close as I can get to sense (2), and it remains ambiguous:

> Je ne voulais pas pleurer, pas encore.

I note that the situation is similar in English; the first sense is easy to capture ("I didn't yet want to cry") but I can't think of a concise way to disambiguate the second.

Answer (score 2):

Cette construction n'est pas du bon français, vraiment. La plus probable des intentions du locuteur en utilisant une telle construction est presque à coup sûr celle exprimée dans la phrase suivante, que je conçois comme correcte, mais évidemment comme seulement une possibilité parmi d'autres.

- Je ne voulais pas pleurer encore. [1]

La phrase suivante rend la même idée plus évidente.

- Je ne voulais pas pleurer encore une fois. [2]

Le déplacement du cc au début change le sens, qui n'est plus celui de la phrase de diction douteuse.

- (Encore une fois, je ne voulais pas pleurer. (*J'avais eu envie de pleurer dans le passé et chaque fois je ne le voulais pas, et cette fois-ci encore—la fois dont il était question dans l'énonciation—, je ne le voulais pas non plus.*))

Ni « 1. » ni « 2. » ne correspondent ; les sens correspondants se rendraient comme ci-dessous.

- (1.) Plus tard j'aurais peut-être pleuré, mais pour le moment je n'en avais pas envie.
- (2.) J'avais envie de pleurer, mais je voulais m'en empêcher pour le moment.

"Je n'avais pas encore envie de pleurer." ne peut pas être une possibilité parce que "vouloir" exprime une volition, une simple  décision, un acte raisonné, alors qu'"avoir envie" dans ce cas  exprime un état d'esprit auquel on est sujet et que l'on n'est pas capable  d'éviter ou de créer.

"Je ne voulais pas pleurer, pas encore.", en tant que français correct n'est pas non plus un équivalent ; on pourrait dire autrement, et de façon plus expressive, "Je n'avais pas envie de pleurer, pas encore." ou "je n'avais pas encore envie de pleurer.", ce qui est différent de « [1] » et « [2] ».

Comment: L'intention n'est pas de dire *encore une fois* "again", mais *pas encore* "not yet, but in the future". Est-ce que cette dernière interprétation de phrase est impossible ?

Comment: @LukeSawczak Si c'était cette intention on aurait un cas d'anglicisme caractérisé : I did not yet want (je ne voulais pas)  (encore) to cry (pleurer). Ça n'est pas une interprétation possible non plus parce que l'on ne peut pas donner à « vouloir » le sens de « avoir envie de » pour le concept « pleurer » (psychophysiologique) ; en fait, on aurait recours à d'autres formes, de façon à rester bien clair ;  (1/3)

Comment: @LukeSawczak par exemple « Pour le moment je ne voulais pas pleurer », qui, néanmoins reflète un état d'esprit étrange comme l'être humain  ne semblent pas capable ou désireux d'une telle sorte de contrôle sur ses réactions (on tend vers le concept d'un robinet que l'on ouvre et que l'on ferme à volonté). Si on utilise « avoir envie de », alors cette interprétation devient la seule possible. (« Je n'avais pas encore envie de pleurer. ») et elle représente un état de chose reconnu, tout à fait normal. (2/3)

Comment: @LukeSawczak  On ne peut pas confondre « vouloir » et « avoir envie », pas dans ce cas. « Elle veut une bicyclette. » peut être exprimé par « Elle a envie d'une bicyclette. », mais l'envie dans « avoir envie de pleurer » n'est plus un désir ; il s'agit en fait de deux sortes d'envie..  (3/3)

Answer (score 2):

The sentence *Je ne voulais pas encore pleurer* sounds usual, nothing incorrect.

It is theoretically ambiguous but the meaning that will be understood is *Je ne voulais pas pleurer une nouvelle fois*: "I didn't want to cry once again" i.e. "I wanted to but refrained from crying." <s>I believe it's also what means "I wanted to cry, but not for said crying to happen yet."</s>

The first interpretation "Later on I might want to cry, but I didn't yet have such a desire" would probably be translated to *J'aurais peut-être voulu pleurer, mais plus tard*.

From your comment that clarifies "but not for said crying to happen yet", I suspect you want to say:

> *Je ne voulais pas déjà pleurer.* (I was too soon for me to cry)

Note that *pleurer* affects a lot how *pas encore* is understood. For example the sentence:

> *Je ne voulais pas encore te le dire.*

more implies the "yet" meaning, otherwise, that would have been:

> *Je ne voulais pas te le redire/te le répéter.*

Comment: Interesting. Both you and LPH identified a meaning I didn't foresee at all. My interest now would be in how to express "not yet" without (a) being *lourd* (this is in a poem), nor (b) accidentally expressing "not again".

Comment: Ahh! *Déjà* is great — merci. Now I suspect that reduces it to the two options that I was asking about with less confusion about the *encore* option.

Comment: @LukeSawczak "Déjà" makes often for an ambiguity in this context, and only the context will permit to tell; this is to say that this is not a solid construction. For instance, in "Ils le voulaient déjà au sommet." there is no way to tell if what is meant is "In those early days they already wanted it/him to be at the top" or "They wanted it/him to be already at the top;"; this means that there is no automatic association of "déjà" with the verb that precedes nor with the complement that follows. This makes for blurred understanding. This is true for other adverbs (toujours, encore, …).

Comment: @LPH The question is about *pas encore pleurer*, not *pas encore/déjà au sommet*.

Comment: @jlliagre What I'm saying is that the often doubtfull association in this construction embodies it with no solid principle of association and one has to think  in order to get at the meaning; therefore, one has to think, because of that, in order to associate "déjà" rather with "pleurer" than with "vouloir".

Comment: @LPH Essaye de t'exprimer simplement et d'aller droit au but plutôt que de faire des phrases tarabiscotées.

Comment: @jlliagre Non, je ne trouve rien de tarabiscoté dans mes propos, mais ce que je trouve c'est qu'ils ne concernent pas des choses toutes simples, et de ce fait ils sont forcément d'une certaine complexité.